# Aviary for Android - How to force crop image using editor.launch

Tags: java, android, image, android-fragments, aviary

How can I force crop image using Aviary for Android. ?

When I take a picture, the aviary editor will be called, then I need to force crop the image as Square. here is a sample for the web. I need to find out how to do it for Android grammatically.

```
editor.launch({
  'image': ...,
  'url': ...,
  forceCropPreset: ['My Size','2:1']  
});
```

Thanks